# Does Time Machine backup programs like Photoshop and iWork?

Tags: time-machine, backup, ssd

I want to upgrade my OS X to Yosemite from Lion and also upgrade my HDD to a SSD but im worried about loosing my programs since I don't have the installers or serial keys. Specifically Adobe cs5 master collection and iWork.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the apps like PhotoShop just come across with all the right licenses.  However, sometimes you must contact the vendor if they have a draconian DRM policy where they are tied to a specific machine / OS.

I'd be very concerned with Adobe if it was a **new machine** but I've done the upgrade "in place" for Creative Suite at least twice on my MBP 2010.

To upgrade "in place" I just allow the installer to do its thing, and only keep Time Machine in the loop for catastrophes.  If I'm super paranoid I'll take a disk image onto USB using some program like SuperDuper!

Comment: Let me know how it turns out, and if your licenses came through.